# How to change the XFCE display profile via command line?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, xfce

I can configure different display profiles using the `xfce4-display-settings` command, and I know that I can query which display profile is currently in use with the command

```
xfconf-query -c displays -p /ActiveProfile
```

which gives me the ID of the current profile. Is it possible to change the display profile using the command line? I tried

```
xfconf-query -c displays -p /ActiveProfile -s <PROFILE ID>
```

but while this changes the output of `xfconf-query -c displays -p /ActiveProfile`, it does not actually change the configuration of my monitors.

Comment: This version of `autorandr` is perfect. Simply set up a configuration and call `autorandr` with a profile name to save it, then you can load configurations by calling again with the profile name: https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr/

Answer (score 6):

The following should work. I tired with XFCE 4.16.

```
xfconf-query --create --type string -c displays -p /Schemes/Apply -s <PROFILE>
```

Comment: Also, the following command will show the human-readable name for a given display ID:
xfconf-query -c displays -p /<PROFILE>

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://github.com/KeyofBlueS/xfce4-display-profile-chooser

> With this bash script you can, via command line, list, set and remove already configured display profiles in xfce4-display-settings. This is useful if you want e.g. to automate stuff by setting profiles within a script or to use a keyboard shortcut. A graphical user interface is provided with yad.

hope it helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1198478)

Comment: That's a link to a script, upstream, if that link becomes invalid, any essential parts included here will still be useless.

Answer (score 0):

This Python script is very simple and effective: https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr/

First install the script:

```
pip install autorandr
```

Then, with your monitors set up in a particular configuration you normally use, call autorandr to save the configuration:

```
autorandr --save foo
```

You can do this multiple times, for different monitor set-ups.
Now you can switch to a saved set-up just by loading it by name:

```
autorandr --load foo
```

You can check which set-up you are using right now:

```
autorandr
```

And you can get autorandr to choose a set-up based on the monitors you have connected right now:

```
autorandr --change
```

As a precaution, you can also give a fall-back profile in case there's a combination of monitors and set-ups that don't work:

```
autorandr --change --default laptop
```

The configuration profiles are saved in `~/.config/autorandr/` using a directory for each profile named with the name of the profile. There are all sorts of hooks available as well that can be used by placing specifically named scripts in the appropriate directory. Refer to the repo given at the top of this answer for further information.

Thanks to this answer for putting me onto this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22462/357604